# Send long Variable to a PHP file in Android

Tags: android, http

I have a function in my Android app that sends a long string to a PHP file which inserts it into a database.
Now, my problem is, that the PHP file never get the whole string from my application.

Is it possible that my string is shortened if i send it as a Http parameter? Or do you have an idea whats possible wrong?

(i'm Sorry for my bad english, i'm not a native speaker)

My Java Code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://********/********/Map/addMarkers.php");
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    try {   
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("marker",
    Functions.ObjToString(spM[i].getMarkerToSave()+"")));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("database",database[spM[i].getType()]));  
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    Log.d("Marker als String ",Functions.ObjToString(spM[i].getMarkerToSave())+"");
    Log.d("Database",database[spM[i].getType()]);
    BufferedReader  in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.d("Antwort des Servers:     ",line);
}
    in.close(); 
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My PHP Code:

```
<?php 
$db = @new mysqli('XXXXXXX', 'dbXXXXX', 'XXXX', 'dbXXXXX');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 die('Konnte keine Verbindung zur Datenbank aufbauen: '.mysqli_connect_error().'('.mysqli_connect_errno().')');
}
$marker_toString = $_POST["marker"];
$db_name= $_POST["database"];
$sql = "INSERT INTO $db_name (marker_toString) VALUES ('$marker_toString')";
echo "marker:    $marker_toString";
echo "db:        $db_name";
$eintragen = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
```

?>

Antwort des Servers:

> Logfile:
>
> > Marker als String    r000ACXNyAC9jb20uxweansmsdfpiwenfefnwiwnfepwnfpn.......
> >
> > Database                 park_markers
> >
> > Antwort des Servers:  marker:    rO0ABXQAClNrYXRlLVNob3A=  db:    ********

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: Do you call that `shortened`? It's completely different.

Answer (score 0):

You are url encoding your name value pairs. Probably you have to url decode them on php side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
How can i do this in php?